# How to assure that the values in a properties file belong to the keyset of another properties file?

Tags: java, resourcebundle, properties-file

I came up with this case when I tried to refactor a server, that responded to requests based on whether some literals existed or not inside the request. The following code pretty much sums it up.

```
if (request.contains("AAA")) {
    send(SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
} else if (request.contains("BBB")) {
    send(FAILURE_RESPONSE);
} ...
```

So, I created a responses.properties file, that contained the possible responses and a key to identify each of them:

```
SUCCESS_RESPONSE=<here there is a big successful response>
FAILURE_RESPONSE=<here there is a smaller failure response>
...
```

and a requests.properties file, that contained the literal to be looked for in the request and the response that the server will send if the key is encountered:

```
AAA=SUCCESS_RESPONSE
BBB=FAILURE_RESPONSE
...
```

and my server side code was refactored to this:

```
ResourceBundle responses = ResourceBundle.getBundle("responses");
ResourceBundle requests = ResourceBundle.getBundle("requests);
...
for (String requestKey : requests.keySet()) {
    if (clientRequest.contains(requestKey)) {
        send(responses.getString(requests.getString(requestKey)));
        break;
    }
}
```

which is definitely more elegant than the initial one.

But what troubled me is that now you have to be sure that the requests.properties file contains values only from the responses.properties file's keyset.

I wrote a method that checks this:

```
private static boolean resourceBundlesAreWellStructured() {
    Set<String> responseKeys = responses.keySet();
    for (String requestKey : requests.keySet()) {
        String requestValue = requests.getString(requestKey);
        if (!responseKeys.contains(requestValue)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but I feel like I am violating the DRY principle this way. So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to use this properties file schema and be sure that the properties file are well structured for my case?
2. Is there another, more elegant way to achieve refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

You method is quite good, except one unneeded assignment line. You could write like this:

```
private static boolean resourceBundlesAreWellStructured() {
    for (String requestKey : requests.keySet()) {
        String requestValue = requests.getString(requestKey);
        if (!responses.containsKey(requestValue)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you use Java 8, you can write same thing with `stream()`:

```
private static boolean resourceBundlesAreWellStructured() {
    return requests.keySet().stream().noneMatch(
        key->!responses.containsKey(requests.getString(key))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken! Yes, Java 8 has some great features but I had to stick with Java 7 for this project...